# Determine values in a database that occur before a certain date, but not after that date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to determine if a certain field value in a database table occurs before a certain date, but not after that date.

I can determine the values that occur before the cutoff date with a simple select, but there may be records after that date.

The field values that I am using are the 'entereddate' and the value I am looking for (in this case a carriercode).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does your schema and data look like?

Comment: The enteredate comes from BillTBL, while the carriercode comes from a carriertbl.  I am joining these through a carrier_key.  My where clause has simply been where billentereddate < '2009-09-01'.  This does give me a list of carriercodes, but this result does not preclude records greater than that date with that carriercode.

Comment: I am not sure if @StevieG would be happy about your answer.

Comment: Sorry, not trying to be difficult, but it is a pretty large schema and difficult to explain.  The enteredate is in datetime format, the carriercode is varchar.  The primary key for the Billtbl is a bill_key, the primary key for the carriertbl is a carrier_key.  Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can do without seeing the data structure.

```
SELECT *
FROM BillTBL a
INNER JOIN carriertbl b ON a.carrier_key = b.carrier_key
WHERE a.billentereddate < '2009-09-01'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM BillTBL 
                WHERE whatever_the_key_is = a.whatever_the_key_is
                AND billentereddate > '2009-09-01')
```

Comment: Thanks StevieG.  This gave me enough to get started.  I got the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.carriercode
    from carriertbl as a
        inner join BillTBL as b ON b.carrier_key = a.carrier_key and b.enteredate < '2009-09-01'
```

Maybe you have to ajust some column name...

Comment: This was a start (and where I started when I first looked at it), but even once you restrict it to records that were entered before a particular date, there may be records entered after that date.  My objective was to only get the values that occurred before that date but did not occur after that date.